# Spark AR script cannot merge Patches with Scene

Tags: javascript, typescript, facebook, instagram, spark-ar-studio

I'm a beginner at Spark AR and I'm trying to build a blink counting game and I got the following error when I try to merge Scene and Patches.

```
Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Promise<SceneObjectBase>'.
```

here's my code

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');

// Use export keyword to make a symbol available in scripting debug console
export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');


(async function () {  // Enables async/await in JS [part 1]

  // To access scene objects
  const [directionalLight] = await Promise.all([
    Scene.root.findFirst('directionalLight0')
  ]);

  var textScore = Scene.root.findFirst('score_number');
  var patchScore = Patches.outputs.getScalar('ScoreJumps');

  // To access class properties
  const directionalLightIntensity = directionalLight.intensity;

  // To log messages to the console
  textScore.text = patchScore.toString();


  Diagnostics.log('Console message logged from the script.');

})(); // Enables async/await in JS [part 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

`findFirst` is a `Promise` so you need to `await` on it:

```
const textScore = await Scene.root.findFirst('score_number');
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried this but I'm still getting the same error "Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Promise<SceneObjectBase>'."

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

I was able to solve my issue by adding @ts-ignore to my code as follows.

```
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Patches = require('Patches');

// Use export keyword to make a symbol available in scripting debug console
export const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');

// To use variables and functions across files, use export/import keyword
// export const animationDuration = 10;

// Use import keyword to import a symbol from another file
// import { animationDuration } from './script.js'

(async function () {  // Enables async/await in JS [part 1]

  // To access scene objects
  const [directionalLight] = await Promise.all([
    Scene.root.findFirst('directionalLight0')
  ]);


  var countNum = await Scene.root.findFirst('number');
  var scoreNumber = (await Patches.outputs.getScalar('score'));

  // To access class properties
  const directionalLightIntensity = directionalLight.intensity;

  // @ts-ignore
  countNum.text = scoreNumber.toString();

  // @ts-ignore
  Diagnostics.log("wererwerwe"+countNum.text);
  
  

  // To log messages to the console
  Diagnostics.log('Console message logged from the script.');

})(); // Enables async/await in JS [part 2]
```